# How to implement customGet in restangular?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, restangular

How to implement `customGet` from `restangular`?

I wrote some code in a server like this:

**user.controller.js**:

```
exports.getRunner = function(req, res) {
  User.find({provider: "instagram"}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    res.json(200, users);
  });
};
```

**index.js**:

```
router.get('/getRunner', controller.getRunner);
```

If I try to get data from postman... it responds the right json data, it works properly.

But when I try using `Restangular customGet` in my client side, I get instead an `undefined` error.

This is my client side:

```
Restangular.all('users').customGET('getRunner').then(function(teams) {
  $scope.teams = teams;
});
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you want, please improve your question

Comment: fix the problem, i'm just change getRunner in server controller with using aggregate :)